# return the only number in the range that is missing from the array

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to use hash table to solve this question. The question description is: "Given an array nums containing n distinct numbers in the range [0, n], return the only number in the range that is missing from the array."

My approach so far is to import the dictionary and use it as a list. Then I am enumerating through the integer array that is given to me. So, for now, nums=[0,1,2,3,4,6]. I have to return number 5 as the missing number. After enumerating, I am trying to go over the items of the dictionary and see which number is missing. If the length of the v is none inside the index, then I will return this line int((((length * (length+1))/2) - sums))

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 class Solution(object):
     def missingNumber(self, nums):
         d = defaultdict(list)
         length = len(nums)
         sums = sum(nums)
         for numbers, index in enumerate(nums):
             d[index].append(numbers)
         
         for k,v in d.items():
             if len(v) == 0 :
                 return int((((length * (length+1))/2) - sums))
```

I am confused about how to show the if statement. Like how from the list it can be recognized that 5 is missing. Also, if there are more than 2 numbers are missing, then what approach will be the best to take? As if the example was: nums = [0,1,2,6,8]

Pardon for not having enough knowledge. I am just a beginner trying to practice questions everyday.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the `numbers` list - does it contain all continuous integer numbers?  are they all distinctives... ?

Comment: Maybe try this simple Math approach: `return (z+1 )* z //2 - sum(nums)`    if  z = `len(nums)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `sum` then no loop is required:

```
sum1 = sum(nums)
sum2 = sum(range(n))
missing_num = sum2 - sum1
```

Comment: Well, evaluating `sum(nums)` literally consists in running a loop over `nums` to compute the sum. I'm afraid there's no way to avoid a loop.

Comment: Also note that `sum(range(n))` will *always* be equal to `n * (n-1) // 2`, which is much faster to evaluate than `sum(range(n))` if `n` is large.

Comment: Also, it should be `range(n+1)`, not `range(n)`, to conform with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume more than simply that the list contains indices with one missing? If, for example, we know that the list is sorted, we can get a logarithmic time solution using a binary search.

```py
def bsearch(x: list[int]) -> int:
    """Return missing index in a sorted list."""
    low, high = 0, len(x)
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if x[mid] == mid:
            # lower half have matching indices; explore upper
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            # mid's value is too high; lower half has missing index
            high = mid
    return low
```

It exploits that below the missing value, `i == x[i]`, but after the missing value, the array values are off by one, `i == x[i] + 1`. By testing the middle point in an interval, we can work out whether the missing element is to the left or right, and by doing this, we get a O(log n) solution.

If the elements are not sorted, you can of course sort them first and then do a binary search. A comparison sort would take O(n log n) and a bucket/radix sort O(n). There is nothing much good to say about first sorting the elements, then, as others have suggested, you can get the answer in O(n) without sorting.

I can try to explain that solution in a little more detail.

The sum of all numbers up to `n` is `n * (n+1) // 2`.

```py
sum(range(n+1)) == n * (n+1) // 2
```

So

```
n*(n+1)//2 =  0 + 1 + 2 + ... + i-1 + i + i+1 + ... + n
```

The sum of the numbers that actually appear is `sum(x)`, so if `i` is missing:

```
    sum(x) =  0 + 1 + 2 + ... + i-1 + 0 + i+1 +... + n
```

Subtract the latter from the former and you get the missing value:

```
n*(n+1)//2:    0 + 1 + 2 + ... + i-1 + i + i+1 + ... + n
  - sum(x):  -(0 + 1 + 2 + ... + i-1 + 0 + i+1 + ... + n)
            =  0 + 0 + 0 + ... +  0  + i +  0  + ... + 0
            = i
```

so the solution is

```py
def general_solution(x: list[int]) -> int:
    return len(x) * (len(x) + 1) // 2 - sum(x)
```

Computing `len(x) * (len(x) + 1) // 2` takes constant time, but `sum(x)` takes O(n), so the total running time is O(n).

If your array is sorted, the binary search approach will be much faster, but if the array is not sorted, a linear time solution isn't bad. There will certainly not be need for anything slower than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is my solution.
Subtract the sum of the elements in the list from the sum of the consecutive numbers you have (n * (n+1) / 2) and you will get the result.

```
class Solution:
    def MissingNumber(self, nums):
        l = len(nums)
        total = l * (l + 1) / 2
        sum_giv_list = sum(nums)
        return total - sum_giv_list
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a dict, you can do it in a `for loop`

```
for i in range(n)
    if i not in nums:
        return i
```

if you are not told what `n` is then you can do something like:

```
for i in range(nums[-1])
    if i not in nums:
        return i
```

if there are a possibility of more than one number missing then you can add them to a list before returning them

```
missing_nums = []
for i in range(nums[-1]):
    if i not in nums:
        missing_nums.append(i)
return missing_nums
```

Comment: It's worth converting `num` to a `set` before running the for-loop. Operator `in` is efficient with sets, but inefficient with lists.

Comment: didn't know that, thanks for the info.